# Remote execution of Qt application causes loss of keyboard input on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, qt, eclipse-cdt, gdbserver

I am using Eclipse CDT with Qt plugin. Working on Debian without X, running the GUI with Qt's QWS server.

Simply, I am starting a regular cpp thread doing the logical work and then starting a standart QApplication execution. Works fine on the target machine locally. But when I start the program remotely from Eclipse's Remote System Explorer service or start to debug with gdbserver, the keyboard input is not handled correctly, randomly picks up some of the keyboard events ie, it is in a racing condition. However, the mouse input works just fine.

I am aware the question is not clear enough but I couldn't figure how to focus on the problem. I can provide additional feedback on demand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you get odd behavior with QT and input handling, you've somehow mucked up QT's finite state processing loop.  You're running in a debug environment, which always tends to mess things up just enough to make them more trouble than they're worth.  Can you move to trying to test it on a remote X display?

Comment: Problem still happens if I don't run as debug. Just using the Eclipse's remote terminal to start the release program is enough to achieve the problem. And sadly I can't setup a X display due to company bureaucracies making easy things complicated. Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: you can't install a VM in VirtualBox?  I absolutely loathe company IT policies that get in the way of software engineering.

Comment: Even if I install an X window in a Virtualbox, I don't belive it will help to solve the actual problem in the target system where embedded Linux will be running. They will have different shell handling methods and I am pretty sure the problem is about the shell handling of the embedded Linux.

Comment: X11 shouldn't involve the shell when connecting a X11 client (the program) to an X11 server (the embedded device, it seems like client/server are backwards, but trust me, this is how x11 works).  If for some reason you need to interact with the shell, in general it will be using busybox on an embedded device, but you really should explore the device you need to attach to.  Again, X11 apps should not be interacting with the shell at all.